# How do you create a game overlay that makes the underlying graphics inactive?

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, user-experience

I've created a simple game, and I drew a large rectangle in photoshop with faded edges that I want to use to overlay the game until the user presses "Begin" (on the overlay). The problem I'm currently having is that the stage under the overlay is still responsive (i.e. I can click on the items under the overlay before I press "Begin"). Here's essentially what I'm doing:

```
 @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl10.glClearColor(51f/255f, 51f/255f, 255f/255f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();

    overlay.setColor(0,0,0,150f/255f);
    batch.begin();
    batch.setColor(overlay.getColor());
    batch.draw(overlay, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

Is there a way to inactive the stage's input listener until the "Begin" button on the overlay is pressed? Is this how an overlay type feature over games is typically achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logic goes in your update function rather than your render function. The easiest way to prevent this is with an if statement surrounding your stage interaction code.

```
If (overlay not active)
    Stage.handleinput()
Else
    Overlay.handleinput()
Endif
```